# How do we call a normal function where a coroutine is expected?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

Consider a coroutine which calls into another coroutine:

```
async def foo(bar):
     result = await bar()
     return result
```

This works fine if `bar` is a coroutine.
What do I need to do (i.e. with what do I need to wrap the call to `bar`) so that this code does the right thing if `bar` is a normal function?

It is perfectly possible to define a coroutine with `async def` even if it never does anything asynchronous (i.e. never uses `await`).
However, the question asks how to wrap/modify/call a regular function `bar` inside the code for `foo` such that `bar` can be awaited.

Comment: see also [How can I wrap a synchronous function in an async coroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241221/how-can-i-wrap-a-synchronous-function-in-an-async-coroutine)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply wrap your synchronous function with [asyncio.coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine) if needed:

```
if not asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(bar):
    bar = asyncio.coroutine(bar)
```

Since it is safe to re-wrap a coroutine, the coroutine function test is actually not required:

```
async_bar = asyncio.coroutine(sync_or_async_bar)
```

Therefore, your code can be re-written as follows:

```
async def foo(bar):
     return await asyncio.coroutine(bar)()
```

Comment: This appears to work. Note, interestingly, that `asyncio.coroutine(normal_function)()` is a generator, while `a_coroutine_function()` is a coroutine.

Comment: Is there any way to treat the generator object this returns like a Task object, to call `Task.done()` and see if it is still running for example?

Comment: [*Deprecated since version 3.8, will be removed in version 3.10*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine).  The documentation says to use `async def` instead, but what is the future-proof method of turning a function into a coroutine?